# Parse Facebook Login: How to connect current user to Facebook?

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-login

My app is currently released without any Parse Facebook login. I am working to add this now.

Currently my user's have their Parse account by signing up with username and password.

I am going to add a button in the app to allow that user to link his account to Facebook by using:

```
if !PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser(user) {
            PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user, withReadPermissions: nil, block: {
                (succeeded: Bool?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (succeeded != nil) {
                    QL1("Woohoo, the user is linked with Facebook!")
                } else {
                    QL4("Booo, the user is not linked with Facebook!")
                }
            })
        }
```

The problem is the following:

If user decides to log off and then click on the facebook login button, then Parse library will create a brand new user account for that user and he will "lose" his previous account.
I am trying to come up with a way where when he logs in via Facebook, first I search the User table for the given username. If I cannot find it, then it's a brand new user and all good. But if I can find a record then:

1- I must delete the user that was created in the Facebook log in process
2- I must log out
3- I must login with the user that was found and link his account to facebook (it will probably trigger a second Facebook permission screen, which is also a bad thing...)

Step 1 and 2 I can do... the problem is to programatically log in someone, since the password field is empty when you do a `PFUser.query()`

Can anyone suggest any alternative please?

Another thing I thought was: If user logs in with Facebook and already have an account, I log him off and pop and alert up telling him to login using his password and then link the app from within the app...
This definitely would work, but the UX is not that awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Isnt parse shutdown?

Comment: That doesn't help with the question - but answering to your question: there are plenty of the Parse servers out there, not to mention the Parse Server OpenSource project.